# Type of sweep for front door

Tags: doors, front-door

I need to replace sweep on my front door. The problem is that I don't currently have one on there so I have nothing to take to the hardware store to say, "I need this" so I'm hoping to get some help here. My house was built in the mid-1950s and from perusing the store it seems like what I need isn't very common anymore.

Here are some pictures of the bottom of the door and the threshold.

[image: Threshold]

[image: Bottom of door]

What type of sweep do I need for this threshold? And where can I get it or should I replace the threshold and sweep altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find any parts for this so I ended up replacing the threshold entirely with something like [this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/M-D-Building-Products-36-in-x-1-1-8-in-x-3-3-4-in-Vinyl-Aluminum-Deluxe-High-Rug-Threshold-08029/100181529).